# Problems with filtering: awk: syntax error at source line 1

Tags: unix, awk, terminal

I am trying to filter a .tsv file by selected relevant rows. I had done this a few days ago with the same file, and had had no problems. However today, as I was filtering the file I had the error as below:
awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
>>> /Users/rbs/Desktop/results.e <<< ntries.tsv
awk: bailing out at source line 1

Here is the code I had written into my terminal.
awk -F '{ if ($5 == 20004 || $5 == 41200) print $0; }' ~/Desktop/results.entries.tsv > ~/filtered2.tsv

Other details:
I am using Mac OSX

I apologise if the question is unclear - I am a beginner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include the field separator for the option `-F`.

Try for a CSV:

```
awk -F ',' '{ if ($5 == 20004 || $5 == 41200) print $0; }' ~/Desktop/results.entries.tsv > ~/filtered2.tsv
```